# How to store an old reactive input in R shiny after removing it

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I have the following r shiny application. We first import the library

```
 library(shiny)
```

Now we generate the UI

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
 downloadButton("dl", "Download"),
 textInput("text","word inpput"),
 mainPanel(
 tableOutput("text1")
                      ))
```

Next we generate the server

```
  server <- function(input, output) {

    output$text1 <- renderTable({

      df1<-iris
      df1$text <- input$text
      return(df1)
      })
            }
```

Finally run the app

```
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

We can now add a text to the textbox to dd to the column text in the dataframe output. However, if i remove the word, the dataframe output reverts to its original state owing to reactivity. Is there a way that the change in output can be made permanent so that even if the textinput box value is replaced, the old value reflects along with the new value

Comment: add expected output pls

Comment: Do you want to replace the old text input with the new one when only you desire? or want to have another column like Text2 input which includes the new data.

Comment: More than replace , one needs to add new text to go with the old text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand correctly, please test the below and let me know if it solves your problem or what still needs to be achieved:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    values <- reactiveValues(df1 = iris)

    observeEvent(req(input$text != ""), {
        values$df1[, paste0("text", ncol(values$df1)-ncol(iris))] <- input$text
    })

    output$text1 <- renderTable({
        return(values$df1)
    })
}
```

Comment: You might want to use a `selectInput()` with `multiple = TRUE` to make it more clear.